# Inner Join, como lo uso?

Tags: join, sql-server-2017

Cómo puedo unir estas 2 tablas?

```
SELECT 
  tdc_feccre AS 'Fecha',
  tdc_nomaux AS 'Empresa',
  pvt_codepk AS 'Código del Lugar de Venta'
FROM dbo.TRAN_DOCCOB_TDC
WHERE tdc_feccre BETWEEN '20180507' AND '20180512'

SELECT 
  pvt_codepk AS 'Código del Lugar de Venta', 
  pvt_deslar AS 'Local'
FROM dbo.PUNTO_VENTA_PVT
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT    T.pvt_codepk AS 'Código del Lugar de Venta',
          T.tdc_feccre AS 'Fecha',
          T.tdc_nomaux AS 'Empresa',
          P.pvt_deslar as 'Local'
FROM      dbo.TRAN_DOCCOB_TDC AS T
INNER JOIN dbo.PUNTO_VENTA_PVT AS P
ON         T.pvt_codepk = P.pvt_codepk
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!